# change the style if number is more than value from radio value

Tags: javascript, html

So I have a radio group at the top that outputs the value to a span... Then I have color swatches that adds up the total in a input (or span). What I am wanting to do is change the color of the text to a a bold red if it goes over the radio button value. It is updating dynamically, but I am wondering if I can use a php if statement to change the style. Here is the code for the page.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<link href="style/site-main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

<script>
// When the page is ready
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("input").click(function(event) {
        updateTotal();
    });
});

function updateTotal() {
    var total = 0;
    $("input:checked").each(function() {
        total += parseFloat(this.title);
    });
    $('#TotalCost').val("$" + total.toFixed(2));
}

</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('input[type="radio"]').click(function(){
        if($(this).attr("value")=="5"){
            $(".box").not(".5").hide();
            $(".5").show();
        }
        if($(this).attr("value")=="10"){
            $(".box").not(".10").hide();
            $(".10").show();
        }
        if($(this).attr("value")=="25"){
            $(".box").not(".25").hide();
            $(".25").show();
        }
        if($(this).attr("value")=="50"){
            $(".box").not(".50").hide();
            $(".50").show();
        }
    });
});
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function sum() {
        var clr000 = document.getElementById('000').value;
        var clr010 = document.getElementById('010').value;
        var clr020 = document.getElementById('020').value;
        var clr019 = document.getElementById('019').value;
        var clr021 = document.getElementById('021').value;
        var clr022 = document.getElementById('022').value;
        var clr025 = document.getElementById('025').value;
        var clr026 = document.getElementById('026').value;
        var clr312 = document.getElementById('312').value;
        var clr030 = document.getElementById('030').value;
        var clr031 = document.getElementById('031').value;
        var clr032 = document.getElementById('032').value;
        var clr047 = document.getElementById('047').value;
        var clr034 = document.getElementById('034').value;
        var clr036 = document.getElementById('036').value;
        var clr035 = document.getElementById('035').value;
        var clr404 = document.getElementById('404').value;
        var clr040 = document.getElementById('040').value;
        var clr043 = document.getElementById('043').value;
        var clr042 = document.getElementById('042').value;
        var clr041 = document.getElementById('041').value;
        var clr045 = document.getElementById('045').value;
        var clr562 = document.getElementById('562').value;
        var clr518 = document.getElementById('518').value;
        var clr050 = document.getElementById('050').value;
        var clr065 = document.getElementById('065').value;
        var clr049 = document.getElementById('049').value;
        var clr086 = document.getElementById('086').value;
        var clr067 = document.getElementById('067').value;
        var clr057 = document.getElementById('057').value;
        var clr051 = document.getElementById('051').value;
        var clr098 = document.getElementById('098').value;
        var clr052 = document.getElementById('052').value;
        var clr084 = document.getElementById('084').value;
        var clr053 = document.getElementById('053').value;
        var clr056 = document.getElementById('056').value;
        var clr066 = document.getElementById('066').value;
        var clr054 = document.getElementById('054').value;
        var clr055 = document.getElementById('055').value;
        var clr060 = document.getElementById('060').value;
        var clr613 = document.getElementById('613').value;
        var clr061 = document.getElementById('061').value;
        var clr068 = document.getElementById('068').value;
        var clr062 = document.getElementById('062').value;
        var clr064 = document.getElementById('064').value;
        var clr063 = document.getElementById('063').value;
        var clr080 = document.getElementById('080').value;
        var clr083 = document.getElementById('083').value;
        var clr081 = document.getElementById('081').value;
        var clr082 = document.getElementById('082').value;
        var clr023 = document.getElementById('023').value;
        var clr070 = document.getElementById('070').value;
        var clr073 = document.getElementById('073').value;
        var clr071 = document.getElementById('071').value;
        var clr076 = document.getElementById('076').value;
        var clr074 = document.getElementById('074').value;
        var clr072 = document.getElementById('072').value;
        var clr090 = document.getElementById('090').value;
        var clr091 = document.getElementById('091').value;
        var clr092 = document.getElementById('092').value;

        var result = parseInt(clr000) + parseInt(clr010) + parseInt(clr020) + parseInt(clr019) + parseInt(clr021) + parseInt(clr022) + parseInt(clr025) + parseInt(clr026) + parseInt(clr312) + parseInt(clr030) + parseInt(clr031) + parseInt(clr032) + parseInt(clr047) + parseInt(clr034) + parseInt(clr036) + parseInt(clr035) + parseInt(clr404) + parseInt(clr040) + parseInt(clr043) + parseInt(clr042) + parseInt(clr041) + parseInt(clr045) + parseInt(clr562) + parseInt(clr518) + parseInt(clr050) + parseInt(clr065) + parseInt(clr049) + parseInt(clr086) + parseInt(clr067) + parseInt(clr057) + parseInt(clr051) + parseInt(clr098) + parseInt(clr052) + parseInt(clr084) + parseInt(clr053) + parseInt(clr056) + parseInt(clr066) + parseInt(clr054) + parseInt(clr055) + parseInt(clr060) + parseInt(clr613) + parseInt(clr061) + parseInt(clr068) + parseInt(clr062) + parseInt(clr064) + parseInt(clr063) + parseInt(clr080) + parseInt(clr083) + parseInt(clr081) + parseInt(clr082) + parseInt(clr023) + parseInt(clr070) + parseInt(clr073) + parseInt(clr071) + parseInt(clr076) + parseInt(clr074) + parseInt(clr072) + parseInt(clr090) + parseInt(clr091) + parseInt(clr092);
            if (!isNaN(result)) {
                document.getElementById('ttlQty').value = result;
            }
        }
  </script>
</head>

<body>

<div class="container">
    <div class="header">
      <h3>Package Size</h3> 
<div class="PackContainer">
<div class="radioBtn">
      <label><input type="radio" onclick="myFunction(this.value)" name="packSize" value="5"> 5 sheets</label>
        <label><input type="radio" onclick="myFunction(this.value)" name="packSize" value="10"> 10 sheets</label>
        <label><input type="radio" onclick="myFunction(this.value)" name="packSize" value="25"> 25 sheets</label>
        <label><input type="radio" onclick="myFunction(this.value)" name="packSize" value="50"> 50 sheets</label>
    </div>
    <div class="5 box">$4.45</div>
    <div class="10 box">$8.40</div>
    <div class="25 box">$18.75</div>
    <div class="50 box">$27.50</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="main">
<div class="counter"> <input type="text" id="ttlQty" /> of <span id="result"></span> remaining.  </div>
  <h3>Colors</h3>
  <div class="colorDiv">
<div class="colorBlock" style="background-color:#DCD9E0;">000 clear<input type="text" id="000" value="0" onkeyup="sum();" /><br></div>
<div class="colorBlock" style="background-color:#E8E9ED;">010 white<input type="text" id="010" value="0" onkeyup="sum();" /><br></div>
<div class="colorBlock" style="background-color:#FFAB00;">020<input type="text" id="020" value="0" onkeyup="sum();" /><br></div>
<div class="colorBlock" style="background-color:#E8A800;">019<input type="text" id="019" value="0" onkeyup="sum();" /><br></div>
<div class="colorBlock" style="background-color:#FEC600;">021<input type="text" id="021" value="0" onkeyup="sum();" /><br></div>
<div class="colorBlock" style="background-color:#F5CA01;">022<input type="text" id="022" value="0" onkeyup="sum();" /><br></div>
<div class="colorBlock" style="background-color:#F3E111;">025<input type="text" id="025" value="0" onkeyup="sum();" /><br></div>
<div class="colorBlock" style="background-color:#64000D;">026<input type="text" id="026" value="0" onkeyup="sum();" /><br></div>
<div class="colorBlock" style="background-color:#74000D;">312<input type="text" id="312" value="0" onkeyup="sum();" /><br></div>
<div class="colorBlock" style="background-color:#960816;">030<input type="text" id="030" value="0" onkeyup="sum();" /><br></div>
<div class="colorBlock" style="background-color:#B8000C;">031<input type="text" id="031" value="0" onkeyup="sum();" /><br></div>
<div class="colorBlock" style="background-color:#D10800;">032<input type="text" id="032" value="0" onkeyup="sum();" /><br></div>
<div class="colorBlock" style="background-color:#DA2F01;">047<input type="text" id="047" value="0" onkeyup="sum();" /><br></div>
<div class="colorBlock" style="background-color:#E44B00;">034<input type="text" id="034" value="0" onkeyup="sum();" /><br></div>
<div class="colorBlock" style="background-color:#EF6701;">036<input type="text" id="036" value="0" onkeyup="sum();" /><br></div>
<div class="colorBlock" style="background-color:#FF6E01;">035<input type="text" id="035" value="0" onkeyup="sum();" /><br></div>
<div class="colorBlock" style="background-color:#422871;">404<input type="text" id="404" value="0" onkeyup="sum();" /><br></div>
<div class="colorBlock" style="background-color:#5F2C65;">040<input type="text" id="040" value="0" onkeyup="sum();" /><br></div>
<div class="colorBlock" style="background-color:#785E9F;">043<input type="text" id="043" value="0" onkeyup="sum();" /><br></div>
<div class="colorBlock" style="background-color:#BC91BC;">042<input type="text" id="042" value="0" onkeyup="sum();" /><br></div>
<div class="colorBlock" style="background-color:#C92A6A;">041<input type="text" id="041" value="0" onkeyup="sum();" /><br></div>
<div class="colorBlock" style="background-color:#F385B6;">045<input type="text" id="045" value="0" onkeyup="sum();" /><br></div>
<div class="colorBlock dark" style="background-color:#141D3A;">562<input type="text" id="562" value="0" onkeyup="sum();" /><br></div>
<div class="colorBlock dark" style="background-color:#12143D;">518<input type="text" id="518" value="0" onkeyup="sum();" /><br></div>
<div class="colorBlock dark" style="background-color:#1C2E5C;">050<input type="text" id="050" value="0" onkeyup="sum();" /><br></div>
<div class="colorBlock dark" style="background-color:#10226A;">065<input type="text" id="065" value="0" onkeyup="sum();" /><br></div>
<div class="colorBlock" style="background-color:#142978;">049<input type="text" id="049" value="0" onkeyup="sum();" /><br></div>
<div class="colorBlock" style="background-color:#0F32AA;">086<input type="text" id="086" value="0" onkeyup="sum();" /><br></div>
<div class="colorBlock" style="background-color:#003979;">067<input type="text" id="067" value="0" onkeyup="sum();" /><br></div>
<div class="colorBlock" style="background-color:#013F8C;">057<input type="text" id="057" value="0" onkeyup="sum();" /><br></div>
<div class="colorBlock" style="background-color:#014584;">051<input type="text" id="051" value="0" onkeyup="sum();" /><br></div>
<div class="colorBlock" style="background-color:#014FA2;">098<input type="text" id="098" value="0" onkeyup="sum();" /><br></div>
<div class="colorBlock" style="background-color:#015CAB;">052<input type="text" id="052" value="0" onkeyup="sum();" /><br></div>
<div class="colorBlock" style="background-color:#0173BC;">084<input type="text" id="084" value="0" onkeyup="sum();" /><br></div>
<div class="colorBlock" style="background-color:#0187C4;">053<input type="text" id="053" value="0" onkeyup="sum();" /><br></div>
<div class="colorBlock" style="background-color:#3BA0D4;">056<input type="text" id="056" value="0" onkeyup="sum();" /><br></div>
<div class="colorBlock" style="background-color:#007F8E;">066<input type="text" id="066" value="0" onkeyup="sum();" /><br></div>
<div class="colorBlock" style="background-color:#009999;">054<input type="text" id="054" value="0" onkeyup="sum();" /><br></div>
<div class="colorBlock" style="background-color:#5BCAB7;">055<input type="text" id="055" value="0" onkeyup="sum();" /><br></div>
<div class="colorBlock dark" style="background-color:#013F28;">060<input type="text" id="060" value="0" onkeyup="sum();" /><br></div>
<div class="colorBlock" style="background-color:#005037;">613<input type="text" id="613" value="0" onkeyup="sum();" /><br></div>
<div class="colorBlock" style="background-color:#00784B;">061<input type="text" id="061" value="0" onkeyup="sum();" /><br></div>
<div class="colorBlock" style="background-color:#007843;">068<input type="text" id="068" value="0" onkeyup="sum();" /><br></div>
<div class="colorBlock" style="background-color:#00863F;">062<input type="text" id="062" value="0" onkeyup="sum();" /><br></div>
<div class="colorBlock" style="background-color:#1E9903;">064<input type="text" id="064" value="0" onkeyup="sum();" /><br></div>
<div class="colorBlock" style="background-color:#69A62D;">063<input type="text" id="063" value="0" onkeyup="sum();" /><br></div>
<div class="colorBlock dark" style="background-color:#442F1E;">080<input type="text" id="080" value="0" onkeyup="sum();" /><br></div>
<div class="colorBlock" style="background-color:#B3591D;">083<input type="text" id="083" value="0" onkeyup="sum();" /><br></div>
<div class="colorBlock" style="background-color:#AA885B;">081<input type="text" id="081" value="0" onkeyup="sum();" /><br></div>
<div class="colorBlock" style="background-color:#CFBF9E;">082<input type="text" id="082" value="0" onkeyup="sum();" /><br></div>
<div class="colorBlock" style="background-color:#EFD394;">023<input type="text" id="023" value="0" onkeyup="sum();" /><br></div>
<div class="colorBlock dark" style="background-color:#0E0E10;">070<input type="text" id="070" value="0" onkeyup="sum();" /><br></div>
<div class="colorBlock" style="background-color:#4C4C4C;">073<input type="text" id="073" value="0" onkeyup="sum();" /><br></div>
<div class="colorBlock" style="background-color:#747D7C;">071<input type="text" id="071" value="0" onkeyup="sum();" /><br></div>
<div class="colorBlock" style="background-color:#818588;">076<input type="text" id="076" value="0" onkeyup="sum();" /><br></div>
<div class="colorBlock" style="background-color:#8A8F8B;">074<input type="text" id="074" value="0" onkeyup="sum();" /><br></div>
<div class="colorBlock" style="background-color:#BFC1BE;">072<input type="text" id="072" value="0" onkeyup="sum();" /><br></div>
<div class="colorBlock" style="background-color:#696A6C;">090<input type="text" id="090" value="0" onkeyup="sum();" /><br></div>
<div class="colorBlock" style="background-color:#776233;">091<input type="text" id="091" value="0" onkeyup="sum();" /><br></div>
<div class="colorBlock" style="background-color:#6E401C;">092<input type="text" id="092" value="0" onkeyup="sum();" /><br></div>
    </div>
  <script type="text/javascript">
function hideshow(which){
if (!document.getElementById)
return
if (which.style.display=="none")
which.style.display="block"
else
which.style.display="none"
}
  </script>
</div>
<div class="footer">

<script>
function myFunction(packSize) {
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = packSize;
}
</script>

    <div style="right:10px;"><strong>PACKAGE PRICE</strong><br>
<input name="TotlCost" type="text" id="TotalCost" style="border:1px solid #fff; text-align:right; font-size:38px; font-weight:bolder; color:#3FA9F5; background-color:#333;"  value="$0.00" size="10" readonly/>
</div><!-- Quantity DIVS -->

</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: well, you my friend need to learn `for` loop

Comment: @James Mr.MK is right, your asspiartions exceed your JavaScript knowledge. Research loops, in particular `for` loops, then try simple tests first, then apply it to your app. If you happen to run into a wall (you will, I still run into walls), post a question as you did for this problem, good luck and happy coding, sir.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue:

> What I am wanting to do is change the color of the text to a a bold red if it goes over the radio button value.

Ignoring everything that's wrong with OP's code...

- ...we can add an event listener to the parent of the `.colorBlock`s, `.colorDiv`.
- When a user enters any number in any of the `.colorBlock > input`, a `keyup` event is triggered from `.colorDiv`.
- The value of `#ttlQty` and the text of `#result` are parsed into numbers...
- ...and compared. If the value of `#ttlQty` (`count`) is greater than the value of `#result` (`quantity`)...
- ...`#ttlQty` color will be red...
- ...otherwise it's color is black.

Add the following code under the `myFunction` function:

```
    var rainbow = document.querySelector('.colorDiv');

    rainbow.addEventListener('keyup', function(event) {
      var count = document.getElementById('ttlQty').value;
      var quantity = document.getElementById('result').textContent;
      if (parseFloat(count) > parseFloat(quantity)) {
        document.getElementById('ttlQty').style.color = 'red';
      }
      else {
        document.getElementById('ttlQty').style.color = 'black';
      }
    }, false);
```

#### SNIPPET

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Untitled Document</title>
  <link href="style/site-main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

  <script>
    // When the page is ready
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $("input").click(function(event) {
        updateTotal();
      });
    });

    function updateTotal() {
      var total = 0;
      $("input:checked").each(function() {
        total += parseFloat(this.title);
      });
      $('#TotalCost').val("$" + total.toFixed(2));
    }
  </script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $('input[type="radio"]').click(function() {
        if ($(this).attr("value") == "5") {
          $(".box").not(".5").hide();
          $(".5").show();
        }
        if ($(this).attr("value") == "10") {
          $(".box").not(".10").hide();
          $(".10").show();
        }
        if ($(this).attr("value") == "25") {
          $(".box").not(".25").hide();
          $(".25").show();
        }
        if ($(this).attr("value") == "50") {
          $(".box").not(".50").hide();
          $(".50").show();
        }
      });
    });
  </script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    function sum() {
      var clr000 = document.getElementById('000').value;
      var clr010 = document.getElementById('010').value;
      var clr020 = document.getElementById('020').value;
      var clr019 = document.getElementById('019').value;
      var clr021 = document.getElementById('021').value;
      var clr022 = document.getElementById('022').value;
      var clr025 = document.getElementById('025').value;
      var clr026 = document.getElementById('026').value;
      var clr312 = document.getElementById('312').value;
      var clr030 = document.getElementById('030').value;
      var clr031 = document.getElementById('031').value;
      var clr032 = document.getElementById('032').value;
      var clr047 = document.getElementById('047').value;
      var clr034 = document.getElementById('034').value;
      var clr036 = document.getElementById('036').value;
      var clr035 = document.getElementById('035').value;
      var clr404 = document.getElementById('404').value;
      var clr040 = document.getElementById('040').value;
      var clr043 = document.getElementById('043').value;
      var clr042 = document.getElementById('042').value;
      var clr041 = document.getElementById('041').value;
      var clr045 = document.getElementById('045').value;
      var clr562 = document.getElementById('562').value;
      var clr518 = document.getElementById('518').value;
      var clr050 = document.getElementById('050').value;
      var clr065 = document.getElementById('065').value;
      var clr049 = document.getElementById('049').value;
      var clr086 = document.getElementById('086').value;
      var clr067 = document.getElementById('067').value;
      var clr057 = document.getElementById('057').value;
      var clr051 = document.getElementById('051').value;
      var clr098 = document.getElementById('098').value;
      var clr052 = document.getElementById('052').value;
      var clr084 = document.getElementById('084').value;
      var clr053 = document.getElementById('053').value;
      var clr056 = document.getElementById('056').value;
      var clr066 = document.getElementById('066').value;
      var clr054 = document.getElementById('054').value;
      var clr055 = document.getElementById('055').value;
      var clr060 = document.getElementById('060').value;
      var clr613 = document.getElementById('613').value;
      var clr061 = document.getElementById('061').value;
      var clr068 = document.getElementById('068').value;
      var clr062 = document.getElementById('062').value;
      var clr064 = document.getElementById('064').value;
      var clr063 = document.getElementById('063').value;
      var clr080 = document.getElementById('080').value;
      var clr083 = document.getElementById('083').value;
      var clr081 = document.getElementById('081').value;
      var clr082 = document.getElementById('082').value;
      var clr023 = document.getElementById('023').value;
      var clr070 = document.getElementById('070').value;
      var clr073 = document.getElementById('073').value;
      var clr071 = document.getElementById('071').value;
      var clr076 = document.getElementById('076').value;
      var clr074 = document.getElementById('074').value;
      var clr072 = document.getElementById('072').value;
      var clr090 = document.getElementById('090').value;
      var clr091 = document.getElementById('091').value;
      var clr092 = document.getElementById('092').value;

      var result = parseInt(clr000) + parseInt(clr010) + parseInt(clr020) + parseInt(clr019) + parseInt(clr021) + parseInt(clr022) + parseInt(clr025) + parseInt(clr026) + parseInt(clr312) + parseInt(clr030) + parseInt(clr031) + parseInt(clr032) + parseInt(clr047) + parseInt(clr034) + parseInt(clr036) + parseInt(clr035) + parseInt(clr404) + parseInt(clr040) + parseInt(clr043) + parseInt(clr042) + parseInt(clr041) + parseInt(clr045) + parseInt(clr562) + parseInt(clr518) + parseInt(clr050) + parseInt(clr065) + parseInt(clr049) + parseInt(clr086) + parseInt(clr067) + parseInt(clr057) + parseInt(clr051) + parseInt(clr098) + parseInt(clr052) + parseInt(clr084) + parseInt(clr053) + parseInt(clr056) + parseInt(clr066) + parseInt(clr054) + parseInt(clr055) + parseInt(clr060) + parseInt(clr613) + parseInt(clr061) + parseInt(clr068) + parseInt(clr062) + parseInt(clr064) + parseInt(clr063) + parseInt(clr080) + parseInt(clr083) + parseInt(clr081) + parseInt(clr082) + parseInt(clr023) + parseInt(clr070) + parseInt(clr073) + parseInt(clr071) + parseInt(clr076) + parseInt(clr074) + parseInt(clr072) + parseInt(clr090) + parseInt(clr091) + parseInt(clr092);
      if (!isNaN(result)) {
        document.getElementById('ttlQty').value = result;
      }
    }
  </script>
</head>

<body>

  <div class="container">
    <div class="header">
      <h3>Package Size</h3> 
      <div class="PackContainer">
        <div class="radioBtn">
          <label>
            <input type="radio" onclick="myFunction(this.value)" name="packSize" value="5">5 sheets</label>
          <label>

            <input type="radio" onclick="myFunction(this.value)" name="packSize" value="10">10 sheets</label>
          <label>
            <input type="radio" onclick="myFunction(this.value)" name="packSize" value="25">25 sheets</label>
          <label>
            <input type="radio" onclick="myFunction(this.value)" name="packSize" value="50">50 sheets</label>
        </div>
        <div class="5 box">$4.45</div>
        <div class="10 box">$8.40</div>
        <div class="25 box">$18.75</div>
        <div class="50 box">$27.50</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="main">
      <div class="counter">
        <input type="text" id="ttlQty" />of <span id="result"></span> remaining.</div>
      <h3>Colors</h3>
      <div class="colorDiv">
        <div class="colorBlock" style="background-color:#DCD9E0;">000 clear
          <input type="text" id="000" value="0" onkeyup="sum();" />
          <br>
        </div>
        <div class="colorBlock" style="background-color:#E8E9ED;">010 white
          <input type="text" id="010" value="0" onkeyup="sum();" />
          <br>
        </div>
        <div class="colorBlock" style="background-color:#FFAB00;">020
          <input type="text" id="020" value="0" onkeyup="sum();" />
          <br>
        </div>
        <div class="colorBlock" style="background-color:#E8A800;">019
          <input type="text" id="019" value="0" onkeyup="sum();" />
          <br>
        </div>
        <div class="colorBlock" style="background-color:#FEC600;">021
          <input type="text" id="021" value="0" onkeyup="sum();" />
          <br>
        </div>
        <div class="colorBlock" style="background-color:#F5CA01;">022
          <input type="text" id="022" value="0" onkeyup="sum();" />
          <br>
        </div>
        <div class="colorBlock" style="background-color:#F3E111;">025
          <input type="text" id="025" value="0" onkeyup="sum();" />
          <br>
        </div>
        <div class="colorBlock" style="background-color:#64000D;">026
          <input type="text" id="026" value="0" onkeyup="sum();" />
          <br>
        </div>
        <div class="colorBlock" style="background-color:#74000D;">312
          <input type="text" id="312" value="0" onkeyup="sum();" />
          <br>
        </div>
        <div class="colorBlock" style="background-color:#960816;">030
          <input type="text" id="030" value="0" onkeyup="sum();" />
          <br>
        </div>
        <div class="colorBlock" style="background-color:#B8000C;">031
          <input type="text" id="031" value="0" onkeyup="sum();" />
          <br>
        </div>
        <div class="colorBlock" style="background-color:#D10800;">032
          <input type="text" id="032" value="0" onkeyup="sum();" />
          <br>
        </div>
        <div class="colorBlock" style="background-color:#DA2F01;">047
          <input type="text" id="047" value="0" onkeyup="sum();" />
          <br>
        </div>
        <div class="colorBlock" style="background-color:#E44B00;">034
          <input type="text" id="034" value="0" onkeyup="sum();" />
          <br>
        </div>
        <div class="colorBlock" style="background-color:#EF6701;">036
          <input type="text" id="036" value="0" onkeyup="sum();" />
          <br>
        </div>
        <div class="colorBlock" style="background-color:#FF6E01;">035
          <input type="text" id="035" value="0" onkeyup="sum();" />
          <br>
        </div>
        <div class="colorBlock" style="background-color:#422871;">404
          <input type="text" id="404" value="0" onkeyup="sum();" />
          <br>
        </div>
        <div class="colorBlock" style="background-color:#5F2C65;">040
          <input type="text" id="040" value="0" onkeyup="sum();" />
          <br>
        </div>
        <div class="colorBlock" style="background-color:#785E9F;">043
          <input type="text" id="043" value="0" onkeyup="sum();" />
          <br>
        </div>
        <div class="colorBlock" style="background-color:#BC91BC;">042
          <input type="text" id="042" value="0" onkeyup="sum();" />
          <br>
        </div>
        <div class="colorBlock" style="background-color:#C92A6A;">041
          <input type="text" id="041" value="0" onkeyup="sum();" />
          <br>
        </div>
        <div class="colorBlock" style="background-color:#F385B6;">045
          <input type="text" id="045" value="0" onkeyup="sum();" />
          <br>
        </div>
        <div class="colorBlock dark" style="background-color:#141D3A;">562
          <input type="text" id="562" value="0" onkeyup="sum();" />
          <br>
        </div>
        <div class="colorBlock dark" style="background-color:#12143D;">518
          <input type="text" id="518" value="0" onkeyup="sum();" />
          <br>
        </div>
        <div class="colorBlock dark" style="background-color:#1C2E5C;">050
          <input type="text" id="050" value="0" onkeyup="sum();" />
          <br>
        </div>
        <div class="colorBlock dark" style="background-color:#10226A;">065
          <input type="text" id="065" value="0" onkeyup="sum();" />
          <br>
        </div>
        <div class="colorBlock" style="background-color:#142978;">049
          <input type="text" id="049" value="0" onkeyup="sum();" />
          <br>
        </div>
        <div class="colorBlock" style="background-color:#0F32AA;">086
          <input type="text" id="086" value="0" onkeyup="sum();" />
          <br>
        </div>
        <div class="colorBlock" style="background-color:#003979;">067
          <input type="text" id="067" value="0" onkeyup="sum();" />
          <br>
        </div>
        <div class="colorBlock" style="background-color:#013F8C;">057
          <input type="text" id="057" value="0" onkeyup="sum();" />
          <br>
        </div>
        <div class="colorBlock" style="background-color:#014584;">051
          <input type="text" id="051" value="0" onkeyup="sum();" />
          <br>
        </div>
        <div class="colorBlock" style="background-color:#014FA2;">098
          <input type="text" id="098" value="0" onkeyup="sum();" />
          <br>
        </div>
        <div class="colorBlock" style="background-color:#015CAB;">052
          <input type="text" id="052" value="0" onkeyup="sum();" />
          <br>
        </div>
        <div class="colorBlock" style="background-color:#0173BC;">084
          <input type="text" id="084" value="0" onkeyup="sum();" />
          <br>
        </div>
        <div class="colorBlock" style="background-color:#0187C4;">053
          <input type="text" id="053" value="0" onkeyup="sum();" />
          <br>
        </div>
        <div class="colorBlock" style="background-color:#3BA0D4;">056
          <input type="text" id="056" value="0" onkeyup="sum();" />
          <br>
        </div>
        <div class="colorBlock" style="background-color:#007F8E;">066
          <input type="text" id="066" value="0" onkeyup="sum();" />
          <br>
        </div>
        <div class="colorBlock" style="background-color:#009999;">054
          <input type="text" id="054" value="0" onkeyup="sum();" />
          <br>
        </div>
        <div class="colorBlock" style="background-color:#5BCAB7;">055
          <input type="text" id="055" value="0" onkeyup="sum();" />
          <br>
        </div>
        <div class="colorBlock dark" style="background-color:#013F28;">060
          <input type="text" id="060" value="0" onkeyup="sum();" />
          <br>
        </div>
        <div class="colorBlock" style="background-color:#005037;">613
          <input type="text" id="613" value="0" onkeyup="sum();" />
          <br>
        </div>
        <div class="colorBlock" style="background-color:#00784B;">061
          <input type="text" id="061" value="0" onkeyup="sum();" />
          <br>
        </div>
        <div class="colorBlock" style="background-color:#007843;">068
          <input type="text" id="068" value="0" onkeyup="sum();" />
          <br>
        </div>
        <div class="colorBlock" style="background-color:#00863F;">062
          <input type="text" id="062" value="0" onkeyup="sum();" />
          <br>
        </div>
        <div class="colorBlock" style="background-color:#1E9903;">064
          <input type="text" id="064" value="0" onkeyup="sum();" />
          <br>
        </div>
        <div class="colorBlock" style="background-color:#69A62D;">063
          <input type="text" id="063" value="0" onkeyup="sum();" />
          <br>
        </div>
        <div class="colorBlock dark" style="background-color:#442F1E;">080
          <input type="text" id="080" value="0" onkeyup="sum();" />
          <br>
        </div>
        <div class="colorBlock" style="background-color:#B3591D;">083
          <input type="text" id="083" value="0" onkeyup="sum();" />
          <br>
        </div>
        <div class="colorBlock" style="background-color:#AA885B;">081
          <input type="text" id="081" value="0" onkeyup="sum();" />
          <br>
        </div>
        <div class="colorBlock" style="background-color:#CFBF9E;">082
          <input type="text" id="082" value="0" onkeyup="sum();" />
          <br>
        </div>
        <div class="colorBlock" style="background-color:#EFD394;">023
          <input type="text" id="023" value="0" onkeyup="sum();" />
          <br>
        </div>
        <div class="colorBlock dark" style="background-color:#0E0E10;">070
          <input type="text" id="070" value="0" onkeyup="sum();" />
          <br>
        </div>
        <div class="colorBlock" style="background-color:#4C4C4C;">073
          <input type="text" id="073" value="0" onkeyup="sum();" />
          <br>
        </div>
        <div class="colorBlock" style="background-color:#747D7C;">071
          <input type="text" id="071" value="0" onkeyup="sum();" />
          <br>
        </div>
        <div class="colorBlock" style="background-color:#818588;">076
          <input type="text" id="076" value="0" onkeyup="sum();" />
          <br>
        </div>
        <div class="colorBlock" style="background-color:#8A8F8B;">074
          <input type="text" id="074" value="0" onkeyup="sum();" />
          <br>
        </div>
        <div class="colorBlock" style="background-color:#BFC1BE;">072
          <input type="text" id="072" value="0" onkeyup="sum();" />
          <br>
        </div>
        <div class="colorBlock" style="background-color:#696A6C;">090
          <input type="text" id="090" value="0" onkeyup="sum();" />
          <br>
        </div>
        <div class="colorBlock" style="background-color:#776233;">091
          <input type="text" id="091" value="0" onkeyup="sum();" />
          <br>
        </div>
        <div class="colorBlock" style="background-color:#6E401C;">092
          <input type="text" id="092" value="0" onkeyup="sum();" />
          <br>
        </div>
      </div>
      <script type="text/javascript">
        function hideshow(which) {
          if (!document.getElementById)
            return
          if (which.style.display == "none")
            which.style.display = "block"
          else
            which.style.display = "none"
        }
      </script>
    </div>
    <div class="footer">

      <script>
        function myFunction(packSize) {
          document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = packSize;
        }
        var rainbow = document.querySelector('.colorDiv');

        rainbow.addEventListener('keyup', function(event) {
          var count = document.getElementById('ttlQty').value;
          var quantity = document.getElementById('result').textContent;
          if (parseFloat(count) > parseFloat(quantity)) {
            document.getElementById('ttlQty').style.color = 'red';
          } else {
            document.getElementById('ttlQty').style.color = 'black';
          }
        }, false);
      </script>

      <div style="right:10px;"><strong>PACKAGE PRICE</strong>
        <br>
        <input name="TotlCost" type="text" id="TotalCost" style="border:1px solid #fff; text-align:right; font-size:38px; font-weight:bolder; color:#3FA9F5; background-color:#333;" value="$0.00" size="10" readonly/>
      </div>
      <!-- Quantity DIVS -->

    </div>


  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Oh man. thank you! I know the code is a mess! I piece things together and just Frankenstein it all.

Comment: Your very welcome, sir. Don't forget to click the green **✔**.

Answer (score 0):

So, @zer00one, this totally worked. Thank you!.. Now I am wondering about styling more than jsut the font color. Like maybe the background/highlight color and the font color.
I was thinking..

```
<script>
    function myFunction(packSize) {
      document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = packSize;
    }
    var rainbow = document.querySelector('.colorDiv');

    rainbow.addEventListener('keyup', function(event) {
      var count = document.getElementById('ttlQty').value;
      var quantity = document.getElementById('result').textContent;
      if (parseFloat(count) > parseFloat(quantity)) {
        document.getElementById('ttlQty2').style.color = 'white';
        document.getElementById('ttlQty2').style.background-color = 'red';
      } else {
        document.getElementById('ttlQty2').style.color = 'black';
      }
    }, false);
  </script>
```

But that didnt work as planned.

Comment: SORRY.. I didnt realize that javascript code was different than css when I posted that question.
I changed "style.background-color   (CSS)
to style.backgroundColor   (js)

Thanks for the help!!!!

Comment: You learn fast, that's good. If you have another question, make a new post, it get's too messy and confusing for readers. You know if you made an algorithm based on hexadecimals, you could generate that table dynamically instead of using that huge one. BTW, if my answer helped you resolve the issue don't forget to click the green **✔** on my post below.